# Dynamically add html elements to a Razor Page, Asp.Net Core

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I would like to dynamically add elements to a Razor page in Asp.Net Core like this:

```
@using System
@{
    string Greeting = $"Yo Dawg! {DateTime.Now.ToString()}";
    string GreetingElement = $"<p id='second'>2nd: {Greeting}</p>";
}
<div>
  @*I understand how to do this:*@
  <p id="first">1st: @Greeting</p>

  @*I cannot figure out how to do something like this:*@
  @GreetingElement
</div>
```

The above results in this page source:

```
  <p id="first">1st: Yo Dawg! 3/26/2020 9:22:05 AM</p>

  &lt;p id=&#x27;second&#x27;&gt;2nd: Yo Dawg! 3/26/2020 9:22:05 AM&lt;/p&gt;
</div>
```

And I want to have this:

```
  <p id="first">1st: Yo Dawg! 3/26/2020 9:22:05 AM</p>

  <p id="second">2nd: Yo Dawg! 3/26/2020 9:22:05 AM</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the answer. Try using `@Html.Raw` in cshtml file, like `<p>@Html.Raw(html-content)</p>`.

Doc is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.raw

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters, try changing this:

```
string GreetingElement = $"<p id='second'>2nd: {Greeting}</p>";
```

for this:

```
string GreetingElement = $"&#60;p id&#61;&#39;second&#39;&#62;2nd: &#123;Greeting&#125;&#60;&#47;p&#62;";
```

This might be useful: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. It results this in the html source:
  <p id="first">1st: Yo Dawg! 3/26/2020 12:34:21 PM</p>

  &amp;#60;p id&amp;#61;&amp;#39;second&amp;#39;&amp;#62;2nd: &amp;#123;Greeting&amp;#125;&amp;#60;&amp;#47;p&amp;#62;

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can achieve this functionality with a partial view as follows:

test.cshtml:

```
@model album_tree_view_test.Pages.TestModel

<div>
  <p id="first">1st: @Model.Greeting</p>

  @{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_yo-dawg-partial");
    // Model gets passed to partial view without referencing it.
  }
</div>
```

test.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;

namespace album_tree_view_test.Pages
{
    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Greeting { get; set; }
        public string Marker { get; set; }

        public TestModel()
        {
            Greeting = $"Yo Dawg! {DateTime.Now.ToString()}";
            Marker = "2nd";
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

_yo-dawg-partial.cshtml:

```
@model album_tree_view_test.Pages.TestModel
<p id="@Model.Marker">@Model.Marker: @Model.Greeting</p>
```

Generated Razor page source (excerpt):

```
<p id="first">1st: Yo Dawg! 3/26/2020 1:13:11 PM</p>

<p id="2nd">2nd: Yo Dawg! 3/26/2020 1:13:11 PM</p>
```

I can now use this functionally to generate nodes of tree view model recursively which was the original purpose of my question.